# Can I write a select function run on different db tables in lambda or Entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to EntityFramework and want to know If it is possible to write a Select statement works on different table. As following.

```
public IList<ent_customer> getCustomer()
{
    return db.Customers.Select(a=>new ent_Customers{
         first_name=a.first_name,
         last_name=a.last_Name
    }).ToList();
}
public IList<ent_vendors> getVendors()
{
    return db.Vendors.Select(a=>new ent_vendors{
         first_name=a.first_name,
         last_name=a.last_Name,
         mobile=a.mobile,
         email=a.email
    }).ToList();
}
```

Before I was using one Select,Insert,Update,Delete function for all tables and avoided rewriting of same code in normal 3 tier project.

I tried a lot and google, unfortunately not found any suggestion

## Update

Before in general 3tier One SQLEngine Class maintain SQL Queries and Dynamically generates Select,Delete,Edit etc.
If I have a class dal_Product and I need to get product list then Only I was calling

```
objProduct.Select();// All Productions
objCustomer.Select();//All Customer No need to write two different queries
obj

on above examle .. SQLEngine were automatically generate two queries
 1- "select *from Product"
 2- "Select *from Customer" 

So I was avoiding rewriting for similar queries and functions.
```

Hop know you people understand that I want SQLEngine type of central queries generator based on condition.

Thanks and Advance

Comment: Which query you are expecting? Please provide the expected output. Also provide the SQL query that you want to achieve.

Comment: This asks for a repository pattern i think. Where you can have a generic repository that will select / insert / update / delete what you want. Take a look at this link http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @JordyvanEijk : yes a repository which will work as base class for every dal..

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota ... I want a global function where both select(mentioned) can execute and return type will be different

Comment: @JordyvanEijk  Thank You very much I was searching same ... Thanks a lot

Comment: @Own i added my comment as anwer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you can use a [`Generic Repository (pattern)`](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)
That will take care of the `CRUD` actions.

Be aware that some people say that having a generic repository pattern is [bad practice](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/03/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/#theonlythingyoucoulddoworserepositoryt) because it's not what they are meant for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean by "works on different table", but let me suggest:
1. Use Repository Pattern as @Jordy van Eijk suggest.
2. Use .Include() / .Load() if you need to work on different but related tables  [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Actually I want to design a Central Processor class where Select,Insert,Update,Delete queries can dynamically generates . I dont need to write EF quires every time in each dal class.

Comment: @Own, look like you want re-invent EF.

Comment: haa haaa .... but unfortunately I am not so genius :) ... I only want to minimize to writing of similar code. Right know I my every DAL 80% of codes are similar EF queries and I am just checking If I can minimize it or not